# Set of enumerate items in list in Python

Tags: python

I need to create a lot of sets of numbers. I add my output and the output that I need.
I wrote the first item output of my list, then I need the same for all items.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for index, item in enumerate(a):
    index_0 = index
    index_1 = index + 1
    index_2 = index + 2
    index_3 = index + 3
    print((a[index_0], a[index_1], a[index_2], a[index_3]))
>>>
1, 2, 3, 4
2, 3, 4, 5
3, 4, 5, 6
4, 5, 6, 7
5, 6, 7, 8
```

What I'm looking for for each item:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,5
1,2,3,6
1,2,3,7
1,2,3,8
1,2,4,5
1,2,4,6
1,2,4,7
1,2,4,8
1,2,5,6
1,2,5,7
1,2,5,8
1,2,6,7
1,2,6,8
1,2,7,8
1,3,4,5
1,3,4,6
1,3,4,7
1,3,4,8
1,3,5,6
1,3,5,7
1,3,5,8
1,3,6,7
1,3,6,8
1,3,7,8
1,4,5,6
1,4,5,7
1,4,5,8
1,4,6,7
1,4,6,8
1,4,7,8
1,5,6,7
1,5,7,8
1,6,7,8
```

Comment: Are you looking for every four length combination of the numbers in `a`? If not then you’ve really gotta be more descriptive in your question. Also I hope you realize a `set` is a reserved word in Python and it’s throwing people off that your code uses nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to use `itertools` `combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 4))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 5),
 (1, 2, 3, 6),
 (1, 2, 3, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 8),
 (1, 2, 4, 5),
 (1, 2, 4, 6),
 (1, 2, 4, 7),
 (1, 2, 4, 8),
 (1, 2, 5, 6),
 (1, 2, 5, 7),
 (1, 2, 5, 8),
 (1, 2, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 6, 8),
 (1, 2, 7, 8),
 (1, 3, 4, 5),
 (1, 3, 4, 6),
 (1, 3, 4, 7),
 (1, 3, 4, 8),
 (1, 3, 5, 6),
 (1, 3, 5, 7),
 (1, 3, 5, 8),
 (1, 3, 6, 7),
 (1, 3, 6, 8),
 (1, 3, 7, 8),
 (1, 4, 5, 6),
 (1, 4, 5, 7),
 (1, 4, 5, 8),
 (1, 4, 6, 7),
 (1, 4, 6, 8),
 (1, 4, 7, 8),
 (1, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 5, 6, 8),
 (1, 5, 7, 8),
 (1, 6, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 4, 5),
 (2, 3, 4, 6),
 (2, 3, 4, 7),
 (2, 3, 4, 8),
 (2, 3, 5, 6),
 (2, 3, 5, 7),
 (2, 3, 5, 8),
 (2, 3, 6, 7),
 (2, 3, 6, 8),
 (2, 3, 7, 8),
 (2, 4, 5, 6),
 (2, 4, 5, 7),
 (2, 4, 5, 8),
 (2, 4, 6, 7),
 (2, 4, 6, 8),
 (2, 4, 7, 8),
 (2, 5, 6, 7),
 (2, 5, 6, 8),
 (2, 5, 7, 8),
 (2, 6, 7, 8),
 (3, 4, 5, 6),
 (3, 4, 5, 7),
 (3, 4, 5, 8),
 (3, 4, 6, 7),
 (3, 4, 6, 8),
 (3, 4, 7, 8),
 (3, 5, 6, 7),
 (3, 5, 6, 8),
 (3, 5, 7, 8),
 (3, 6, 7, 8),
 (4, 5, 6, 7),
 (4, 5, 6, 8),
 (4, 5, 7, 8),
 (4, 6, 7, 8),
 (5, 6, 7, 8)]
```

Comment: If I want to add a limit between the numbers for example max 10 values of differencies like: 1,2,3,4 and the max will be 1,2,3,10 and the next will be 1,2,4,5 and the max will be 1,2,4,10... Ahy way to do that?